# RabbitMQ messages not dead-lettered on ttl expiration for a topic queue

Tags: rabbitmq, ttl, dead-letter, rabbitmq-exchange

I have the following configuration

```
{"rabbit_version":"3.4.3",

...

"queues":[
    {"name":"consumer.queue-dl","vhost":"dev","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"arguments":{}},
    {"name":"consumer.queue","vhost":"dev","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"arguments":{"x-message-ttl":1000,"x-dead-letter-exchange":"consumer.exchange-dl"}},
    {"name":"another-queue", "vhost":"dev","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"arguments":{"x-message-ttl":1000,"x-dead-letter-exchange":"consumer.exchange-dl"}},
],

"exchanges":[
    {"name":"consumer.exchange-dl","vhost":"dev","type":"direct","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"internal":false,"arguments":{}},
    {"name":"consumer.exchange","vhost":"dev","type":"topic","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"internal":false,"arguments":{}},
    {"name":"another-exchange","vhost":"dev","type":"direct","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"internal":false,"arguments":{}}
],

"bindings":[
    {"source":"consumer.exchange-dl","vhost":"dev","destination":"consumer.queue-dl","destination_type":"queue","routing_key":"","arguments":{}},
    {"source":"consumer.exchange-dl","vhost":"dev","destination":"consumer.queue-dl","destination_type":"queue","routing_key":"#","arguments":{}},
    {"source":"consumer.exchange","vhost":"dev","destination":"consumer.queue","destination_type":"queue","routing_key":"consumer.topic2","arguments":{}},
    {"source":"another-exchange","vhost":"dev","destination":"another-queue","destination_type":"queue","routing_key":"","arguments":{}}
]}
```

I set a DLX on **anoter-queue** and **consumer.queue** so their messages are moved to **consumer.exchange-dl** after 1 second.

Everything works fine for **another-queue** which is bound to **another-exchange** (direct); the messages sent to **consumer.exchange** (topic) are not moved to the DLX. I tried to play with the routing keys bindings for the DLX but nothing worked. Any gotchas on the DLX for topic exhanges?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved creating one more binding on the DLX to the DL queue for the *consumer.topic2*